# NODE.JS Как правильно подключиться к WebSocket с HTTPS?

Tags: javascript, websocket

Есть сервер WebSocket запущенный на порте 9000. Настроен так:

```
    var http = require('http');
var Static = require('node-static');
var WebSocketServer = new require('ws');

// подключенные клиенты
var clients = {};

// WebSocket-сервер на порту 9000
var webSocketServer = new WebSocketServer.Server({
port: 9000
});
webSocketServer.on('connection', function(ws, req) {
```

Как мне правильно подключится к нему с сайта с HTTPS?

Нужен ли мне какой сертификат для wss и как его установить?

Ничего не выходит. Когда использую ws:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS.
```

Пробую использовать wss (просто указываю при создании сокета wss вместо ws, но ничего все равно не выходит - ошибка.

### Научите пожалуйста, как правильно подключиться к WebSocket с HTTPS

При этом если локально запускаю index.html на компьютере, он нормально коннектится к серверу (сервер не локальный т.е. проблемы в портах нет).

### Но когда я заливаю index.html на хост, и пытаюсь подключиться хоть по ws хоть по wss - браузер дает ошибку

Когда перехожу по https://site.com:8443 мне показывает что там не сертификата, может в этом проблема?